# Override object on casting it

Tags: java, android

I want to override `onDraw` of `ListView` without create a new class extended from `ListView`, This is my line that I want to override on it

```
lv_booksList = (ListView) ll_container.findViewById(R.id.lv_booksList);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: not really sure, but i think you'll have to use the inflate method

Answer (score 3):

You cannot* modify Java classes at runtime, nor can you change the type of an object after it has been created. If you want to override `onDraw`, the only way is to create a subclass and instantiate it.